# C# Reflection - GetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a project where `System.Web.Helpers.Webgrid` is being used as a base class for a new grid.
I believe that it uses reflection to invoke private methods of the base class.

Could someone please clarify.......
In the code below, seeing as `GetDefaultColumnsMethod` returns something,  can I presume that `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid` has a method on it named `"GetDefaultColumns"`?

```
private MethodInfo GetDefaultColumnsMethod 
{
    get { return typeof(System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid).GetMethod("GetDefaultColumns", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); }
}

private IEnumerable<WebGridColumn> GetDefaultColumns(IEnumerable<string> exclusions)
{
    return (IEnumerable <WebGridColumn>)GetDefaultColumnsMethod.Invoke((System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid)this, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { exclusions }, null);
}
```

Comment: reference source https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebGrid/WebGrid.cs

Comment: This is specified in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you want to call the method, I suggest testing if it has *expected parameters* as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the code below, seeing as GetDefaultColumnsMethod returns
>   something, can I presume that System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid has a method
>   on it named "GetDefaultColumns"?

Yes.

- `Type.GetMethod` searches for the method specified by its name
- `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` means you search an *instance* method (as opposed to a `static` one) that is not `public` (do note it might me `protected`/`internal` though).

Answer (score 0):

Digging deeper - i added the debug code below and I now have a list of the methods....

So I can now debug and see what is there.....and more to the point, what is not in newer versions of the WebGrid component.

```
    Type tt = this.GetType();
    Type t = tt.BaseType;

    PropertyInfo[] props =
        t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
    MethodInfo[] mths = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
```